# Roots of Unity are distinct

Tags: abstract-algebra

Let $F$ be a field and $p, q\in \mathbb Z$ be distinct positive primes. Show that if $x \in F$ is such that $x^p=x^q=1$ then $x=1$.

I tried to suppose $x \neq 1$ and to do something with the least p and q satisfying the preceding property, but had no success.

Comment: What is the order of $x$ in the group $F^\times$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

More generally, if $m$ and $n$ are relative prime integers and $x^m=x^n=1$, then $x=1$ because for some $a,b\in\mathbb Z$ we have $1=am+bn$, so $x=x^1=(x^m)^a(x^n)^b$.